# RejectedExecutionException using ThreadPoolExecutor and AndroidHttpClient

Tags: android, android-asynctask, threadpoolexecutor

I am using my own ThreadPoolExecutor to know when all my tasks have finished.  I have a method that is a client.get() call and on success, it would do more client.get() calls.  However, I am getting `java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@414ca470 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@414ab1a0[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 1]` when I am calling the client.get() from inside my first success.  How can I fix this error?

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
int limit = 20;
BlockingQueue<Runnable> q = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(limit);
ThreadPoolExecutor executor = 
                        new ThreadPoolExecutor(limit, limit, 20, TimeUnit.SECONDS, q);

client.setThreadPool(executor);

parseSilo(url, context); // this fires client.get() ... as it encounters urls in JSON feed
executor.shutdown();

while (!executor.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
    Log.e(TAG, executor.getTaskCount() + " tasks left");
}
if (executor.isShutdown()) {
     Log.e(TAG, "done");
}
```

parseSilo method

```
public static void parseSilo(String url, final Context context) {
        client.get(url, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String content) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Parsing Silo");
                JsonNode rootNode;

                //json parsing

                // parse collections
                for (Show show : listOfShows) {
                    parseCollections(show.getCollectionUrl()); // another client.get()
                }

            }

        });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are issuing a `client.get()` call after  `executor.shutdown()`  so either to delay `shutdown` after you finish all your `get` calls or don't issue a new one after shutting down your `executor`